# Installed Python 3.7 and tried changing that to the default however, changing $PATH and running python --version still shows 2.7

Tags: python, bash, macos

Sorry if the question is simple or I'm missing something obvious but I'm fairly new with console commands and Python.

As the title suggests, I installed Homebrew and subsequently the latest version of Python. I want to make this the default when running `python --version` in bash.

I tried changing the path in my bash_profile with the following line at the bottom:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
```

It seems that when I install new modules however, that they are for 2.7 and not 3. Checking `pip --version` going straight to the default:

> ```
> pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
> ```

I also tried running the following commands:

```
echo "export Path=/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile && source  ~/.bash_profile
```

this does edit my `bash_profile` again, but the line I wanted (and added manually) isn't the one that appears; instead the following is inserted (I have no idea why Applications/VMware is inserted at the end, it has nothing to do with Python or what I'm trying to do):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATHexport Path=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware
```

Can anyone explain to me how I can make python3 the default. I don't want to get rid of 2.7 obviously because a lot of scripts for mac still depend on it. Would it be possible to install pipenv and run 3.7 from there, while keeping 2.7 at the default?

Comment: You might have been very lucky. Usually replacing the `python` on a UNIXoid system results in many system tools not working anymore. Continue at your own risk.

Comment: use `pip3` and `python3` to run, `idle3` if you use it.

Comment: "*the line I wanted (and added manually) isn't the one that appears*" - Now would be a good time to learn the difference between `"` and `'` in the shell.

Comment: ...also, `export Path` should be `export PATH`.  Environment variables on  UNIX-like systems are case sensitive (not on Windows).

Comment: One better way would be to use conda hence you can create an clean environment with python 3.7 which make thing easier to manage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't want to change this.

First:

> Would it be possible to install pipenv and run 3.7 from there, while keeping 2.7 at the default?

Yes! Install `pipenv`, and set up an environment where 3.7 is the default, but leave the system default at 2.7.

---

More generally:

According to [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/), which isn't due to be reevaluated until 2020, if you don't have a virtual environment activated:

- `python3` runs Python 3.x
- `python2` runs Python 2.x
- `python` usually shouldn't be used—but if you do use it, it should run Python 2.x.

Usually, you'll also have, e.g., `python3.7` and `python2.7` to run specific 3.x and 2.x versions, although this isn't covered by any standard.

Scripts like `pip`, and those installed by `pip`, should be installed with similar suffixes—but ideally, if you have multiple versions, you shouldn't run those scripts. Most of them are designed to be run as modules, so you can run `python3 -m pip` to run the `pip` for your 3.x.

For a few things, it may be handy to set up shortcuts. (For example, instead of running `python3 -m ipython` from the command line, I usually use an iTerm profile that uses that instead of `bash` as my start command. If you don't use either IPython or iTerm, you can make a Terminal.app profile that runs `python3`.)

Scripts installed as part of your platform's package manager are a whole more complicated story, but macOS doesn't have an official package manager, and Homebrew generally expects you to install Python libraries with `pip`, not `brew`, so you don't have to worry about that.

Programs should have an installer—whether they install via `pip` or something like `py2app`—that creates a proper shbang line, so they run with whichever Python version they were installed with, so you don't have to worry about them. But programs that come with your OS may use something like `/usr/bin/env python`, and they will expect that to run the version of Python that came with your OS.

For development purposes, you usually want to use `virtualenv` or `pipenv` or `conda` so that `python` runs the Python interpreter for whichever environment is currently activated.

So, don't try to change the fact that `python` runs Apple's Python 2.7. That's what it's supposed to do, and if you make it do otherwise, you could break things. Use `python3`, `python3 -m pip`, etc.; use `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on your scripts (or, better, use `setuptools` to create entry-point scripts automatically); use virtual environments; just never run `python`, and everything will work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to run command

```
 $which python
```

And then goto the path rename python to python2 
Then run command

```
$which python3
```

To get the path of python3
Just link with command

```
sudo ln -s $python3path /usr/bin
```

/python 
You need to instead $python3path with real path 
Then you can run python3 with python command